# Can't make hba connection work on centos 7

Tags: centos, storage

I am currently using an old server with an old storage connected by fiberchannel. 
On the storage side I left everything configured but on the server side I do not see the disk that was created for it. 
Here is what I have so far:

```
[root@vmprod01 ~]# lspci | grep Fibre
10:00.0 Fibre Channel: Emulex Corporation Zephyr-X LightPulse Fibre Channel Host Adapter (rev 02)
10:00.1 Fibre Channel: Emulex Corporation Zephyr-X LightPulse Fibre Channel Host Adapter (rev 02)
```

info:

```
[root@vmprod01 ~]# lspci -v -s 10:00.0
10:00.0 Fibre Channel: Emulex Corporation Zephyr-X LightPulse Fibre Channel Host Adapter (rev 02)
        Subsystem: Emulex Corporation Zephyr-X LightPulse Fibre Channel Host Adapter
        Physical Slot: 2
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 26
        Memory at c7eff000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Memory at c7efec00 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
        I/O ports at 6000 [size=256]
        [virtual] Expansion ROM at c6000000 [disabled] [size=256K]
        Capabilities: [58] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/16 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [44] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [12c] Power Budgeting <?>
        Kernel driver in use: lpfc
```

so then i need to know if the kernel driver is loaded right?

```
root@vmprod01 ~]# lsmod | grep lpfc
lpfc                  702870  0 
crc_t10dif             12714  3 lpfc,target_core_mod,sd_mod
scsi_transport_fc      64056  1 lpfc
[root@vmprod01 ~]# modinfo lpfc
filename:       /lib/modules/3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/scsi/lpfc/lpfc.ko
version:        0:10.7.0.1
author:         Emulex Corporation - tech.support@emulex.com
description:    Emulex LightPulse Fibre Channel SCSI driver 10.7.0.1
license:        GPL
rhelversion:    7.2
srcversion:     053424650970DDDDCE74F8C
-
-
-
```

OK looks like it's loadead right?
What else I have to check/do to have it working?
Remember I'm totally new at this.

Regards,
Maniat1k.-

I already try to find the solution, then asked in the CentOS forums: https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=60223&p=254367#p254367

But have no luck with that.

Comment: Try this: http://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/linux/18/fc-hba-linux.html

Answer (score 1):

A couple things to try:

1. try rescanning the SCSI bus as follows:

   ```
   echo "- - -" | sudo tee /sys/class/scsi_host/host*/scan
   ```
2. Check to see if it's just the device nodes under /dev which are missing (thanks to a slow / malfunctioning udev).  If your devices show up in /proc/partitions, you can manually create the device nodes under /dev using the mknod command using the major / minor IDs found in that file.  NB: this isn't a particularly elegant solution, but writing and fixing udev rules is a book unto itself.